# How to know the name of the file where the error is triggering in Joomla?

Tags: migration, error-reporting

I am migrating a Joomla 3 website, but I am getting an error message.  The issue is that Joomla is showing an error message, but it doesn't show the name of the file where the error is triggering.

Any help with this?

Please note, I'm not asking about how to migrate the website, I'm just asking how to show the name of the file where the error is triggering.

Comment: Please post ALL Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange (a community that was specifically created to field Joomla questions).  Would you like this question to be migrated to JSE by Stack Overflow moderators?

Comment: Ok, you can migrate it  ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the Joomla Global Configuration, increase the Error Reporting Level. Depending on where the exception occurs, you might also have to enable the Debug Mode.

Comment: I see that you are devoting some recent effort on Joomla questions on Stack Overflow.  We'd love to you have you help with answering some of our [joomla.se] Stack Exchange questions.